# Do a for loop with just some array elements

Tags: excel, vba

I guess this is a easy one but I can't figure it out.

I have an array with multiple items, as it follows:

```
slds = Array(3, 15, 27, 39, 51, 87, 74, 89, 11, 45, 57, 24)
```

I want to do a `For` loop using just some items the array, defined by the position, for example, the first 4 elements, but I don't know the correct syntax for it. Something like

```
For slds(0) to slds(3) 'do some...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `For i = lBound(slds) to Lbound(slds) + 3`  Then use slds(i) to refer to the item.

Comment: `For i = 0 to 3: msgbox slds(i): next i` for example.

Comment: or just redim the array to your chosen length.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a typical zero-based array in VBA:

```
For i = 0 To 3
    'do stuff
    Debug.Print slds(i)
Next
```

Here you are indicating you want index 0 to 3, or the first 4 elements.

If you can't be certain of zero-based, you'd use
`For i = lBound(slds) to Lbound(slds) + 3`as mentioned by [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531580/do-a-for-loop-with-just-some-array-elements/34531615#comment56804521_34531580)

Answer (score 2):

Or you could just `Redim` the array to capture the first *x* values.

For loop retained in case you still want to loop.

```
Sub a()
Dim slds
Dim lngCnt As Long
slds = Array(3, 15, 27, 39, 51, 87, 74, 89, 11, 45, 57, 24)
ReDim Preserve slds(1 To 3)
For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(slds)
    Debug.Print slds(lngCnt)
Next
End Sub
```